# claws-mail suddenly does not recognize my .claws-mail folder

Tags: claws-mail

I turned my computer on today like any other day, and fired up my email-client claws-mail. However, instead of showing me my inbox, it just pops up the new-account wizard, as though my .claws-mail folder did not exist! I've double-checked that it's there, and that it (seems to) contain everything that it should.

I tried running claws-mail from the terminal to see if it returned any useful messages about why it couldn't find my email account, but no dice...

For reference, this is CM version 3.7.2 running on Gentoo kernel 2.6.31-gentoo-r6 (x86_64)

Any clues as to how to get my beloved inbox/config back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me a couple times now, but thankfully I've foundthe fix - somehow my folderlist.xml file gets truncated (emptied), but thankfully claws-mail keeps a backup:

```
cp .claws-mail/folderlist.xml.bak .claws-mail/folderlist.xml
```

fixes the problem